# How to reassign a keybinding to a function

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, plugin-nerdtree

I'm using the `byobu` terminal so the keys `F2`, `F3`, and `F4` (and others) are for the `byobu` commands.

In my `.vimrc` I have the following:

```
silent! nmap <C-p> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
silent! map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
silent! map <F3> :NERDTreeFind<CR>
let g:NERDTreeToggle="<F2>"
let g:NERDTreeMapActivateNode="<F3>"
let g:NERDTreeMapPreview="<F4>"
```

I would that the keybindings would be `\q`, `\w`, and `\e` respectively.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to put the following:

```
let g:NERDTreeToggle="<leader>q"
let g:NERDTreeMapActivateNode="<leader>w"
let g:NERDTreeMapPreview="<leader>e"
```

assuming that `\` is your leader, which it is by default.